# Swift: Multipeer connectivity: Reconnect

Tags: ios, swift, multipeer-connectivity

I have tried to set up an app that communicate with about 5-6 devices at the same time. However, I found that as times go by, some of the devices may auto-disconnected. Once it is disconnected, it cannot rejoin the others.

The func didChangeState:MCSessionState did called and then tells that the device disconnected. Any method to auto-reconnect to the others if it is found disconnected?